# where should i paste my html form code in joomla?

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm working in joomla i have one `custom contact form`
i have created that in `html code` and when user click on `submit` button
i should get all textbox values `email` to me.

so i write `php code` for that.

for e.g
there are only two fields
in html code
in php code like below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    $email_to = "test@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "mail";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // add  validation for other fields if needed 
    if(!isset($_POST['Applicant_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']))) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

     //all fields with there name to send in email
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email= $_POST['email']; // required


    $error_message = "";

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

     //show all fields in message body
    $email_message .= "Applicant_name: ".clean_string($Applicant_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "name: ".clean_string($dob)."\n";
    $email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($sex)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

> where and how I need to paste this code in Joomla?

Comment: Don't use custom PHP code for this. Read about [JMail](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)

Comment: @Lodder thanks for thread 
but how do I do in my case what about html page?

Comment: You should create a simple Joomla module. There is lots of [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Module_Development) on how to do this. Or have a look at the Joomla Extensions Directory for pre-made extensions, some of which might suit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the core contact form and make a plugin to add some fields.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to just install an extension to handle forms.

I suggest you to [install](http://docs.joomla.org/Installing_an_extension) [RSform Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4964).

Features & Benefits

- Send customized HTML/Text emails with submitted data
- Export gathered data to CSV format
- Field validation rules Customizable thank you
  message
- Customizable thank you message

Comment: is this not a free plugin ? :(

Comment: @ashuthinks - No, it's not free, however it's widely recommended. If you're looking for a free extension then try [ChronoForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508)

Answer (score 1):

If you have decided to use your own code then go to modules from "ADMIN end"  . Click on "NEW" then select "custom html" type and simply paste the code. Now give your module a name and publish it wherever you need.